# SchemaExport don't create my tables in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I recently add the follow service class to my spring project, which has the function to create databse AND tables for the application use:

```
@Service
public class InstallService {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioHome usuario;

    @Autowired
    AutorizacaoHome autorizacao;

    public boolean create_database(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?user="+usuario+"&password="+senha;
            Connection conn = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM pg_database";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                if(rs.getString("datname").equals("horario"))
                    return false;
            }
            sql = "CREATE DATABASE horario WITH OWNER = "+usuario+" ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = 'pt_BR.utf8' LC_CTYPE = 'pt_BR.utf8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        return create_tables(maquina, usuario, senha);
    }

    public boolean create_tables(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setProperty("jdbc.Classname", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        config.setProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/horario?charSet=LATIN1");
        config.setProperty("jdbc.user", usuario);
        config.setProperty("jdbc.pass", senha);
        config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

        SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config);
        schema.create(true, true);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("jdbc.Classname", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        properties.setProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/horario?charSet=LATIN1");
        properties.setProperty("jdbc.user", usuario);
        properties.setProperty("jdbc.pass", senha);
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");

        try {
            File file = new File("database.properties");
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            properties.store(fileOut, "propriedades");
            fileOut.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return autorizacao.persist(new Autorizacao("permissao_teste"));
    }

    public boolean create_user(String login, String senha, String pnome, String unome) {
        Usuario novo = new Usuario(login, senha, pnome, unome);
        novo.setAutorizacao(autorizacao.findALL());
        return usuario.persist(novo);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, and the method create_database is called, this error happens:

```
ERROR: HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
    at com.horariolivre.service.InstallService.create_tables(InstallService.java:71)
    at com.horariolivre.service.InstallService.create_database(InstallService.java:57)
    at com.horariolivre.controller.InstallController.createdb(InstallController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mai 09, 2014 10:02:29 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Mai 09, 2014 10:02:29 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
Mai 09, 2014 10:02:29 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: database "horario" does not exist)
Mai 09, 2014 10:02:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/HorarioLivre2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "horario" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:572)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:177)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.<init>(Jdbc3gConnection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:428)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.horariolivre.dao.AutorizacaoHome$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b21c029b.persist(<generated>)
    at com.horariolivre.service.InstallService.create_tables(InstallService.java:93)
    at com.horariolivre.service.InstallService.create_database(InstallService.java:57)
    at com.horariolivre.controller.InstallController.createdb(InstallController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

My current code is that:

```
@Service
public class InstallService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome usuario;

    @Autowired
    private AutorizacaoHome autorizacao;

    public boolean create_database(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
        }
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/postgres";
            System.out.println("url = "+url);
            System.out.println("usuario = "+usuario);
            System.out.println("senha = "+senha);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = 'horario';");
            rs.next();
            int counter  = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("counter = "+counter);
            if(counter > 0) {
                System.out.println("calling_create_tables");
                create_tables(maquina, usuario, senha);
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
                return true;
            }

            int result = stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE horario WITH OWNER "+usuario+";");
            System.out.println("result = "+result);
            if(result > 0) {
                System.out.println("calling_create_tables");
                create_tables(maquina, usuario, senha);
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("SQLException");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("retornando false");
        return false;
    }

    public void create_tables(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        System.out.println("create_tables");
        create_properties(maquina, usuario, senha);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileInputStream( "database.properties" );
            props.load(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        config.setProperties(props);

        try {
            String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
            SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config, conn);
            schema.create(true, true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        insert_default_values();
    }

    public void insert_default_values() {
        System.out.println("insert_default_values");
        String [] autorizacoes = {"cad_evento", "lista_evento", "cad_horario", "lista_horario", "cad_usuario", "lista_usuario", "cad_campo", "cad_tipo", "cad_permissao"};
        for(int i=0; i<autorizacoes.length; i++) {
            autorizacao.persist(new Autorizacao(autorizacoes[i]));
        }
    }

    public void create_properties(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
        System.out.println("create_properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("jdbc.Classname", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        props.setProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://"+maquina+"/horario" );
        props.setProperty("jdbc.user", usuario );
        props.setProperty("jdbc.pass", senha );

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream( "database.properties" );
            props.store( fos, "propriedades" );
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean create_user(String login, String senha, String pnome, String unome) {
        System.out.println("create_user");
        Usuario novo = new Usuario(login, senha, pnome, unome);

        if(usuario.persist(novo))
            novo.setAutorizacao(autorizacao.findALL());
        else
            return false;

        if(usuario.merge(novo) != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I don't receive any error when the method create_tables is executed, but none table is create in the database, causing an error when I try insert data in the tables.

Anyone can tell me what's wrong? I can't see nothing that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally acomplish my objective, and now both database and tables are being created. The final code for the method create_table(0 is:

```
public void create_tables(String maquina, String usuario, String senha) {
    System.out.println("create_tables");
    create_properties(maquina, usuario, senha);

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileInputStream( "database.properties" );
        props.load(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    config.setProperties(props);

    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Atributo.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.ConfigHorarioLivre.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Evento.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.HorarioLivre.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Key.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Tipo.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Value.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Autorizacao.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Usuario.class);

    try {
        String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
        SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config, conn);
        schema.create(true, true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    insert_default_values();
}
```

Basicly, I include in the method a group of lines with the instruction:

```
config.addAnnotatedClass(com.horariolivre.entity.Atributo.class);
```

where I tell to program what entity classes should be created in the database. That do the job.

Answer (score 0):

@kleber mota it seems that the schema is created from the log file content  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete and i guess since there is no access or grants or privileges provided to that user hibernate could not connect. check using the postgres sql whether the schema is created as a root/admin.

Comment: No, I am using pgAdmin3 to check and none database is created in the server.